# How to calculate an array of stock prices using simulated returns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, finance

I want to simulate an array of stock prices by using simulated returns. For example, I set the initial stock price to be $70 and I created a panda series with 10 periods of returns:

```
returns = pd.Series([1.01,1.02,1.03,1.01,0.99,0.98,1.07,0.99,1.03,1.03])
```

How can I get a series of stock prices with 10 periods?
(the 1st price data should be initial stock price(`70) * 1.01`; the 2nd should be `70 * 1.01 * 1.02`; the 3rd should be ... till the 20th.)

```
initial stock price = 70
returns = pd.Series([1.01,1.02,1.03,1.01,0.99,0.98,1.07,0.99,1.03,1.03])
```

Comment: Thank you and how can I find those relevant questions asked before?

Answer (score 5):

IIUC, use [`cumprod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumprod.html#pandas-dataframe-cumprod):

```
initial_stock_price = 70
returns = pd.Series([1.01,1.02,1.03,1.01,0.99,0.98,1.07,0.99,1.03,1.03])

returns.cumprod() * initial_stock_price
```

Output:

```
0    70.700000
1    72.114000
2    74.277420
3    75.020194
4    74.269992
5    72.784592
6    77.879514
7    77.100719
8    79.413740
9    81.796153
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use reduce to multiply all values in a list then multiple by the price:

```py
from functools import reduce
import pandas as pd
inital_price = 70
returns = pd.Series([1.01,1.02,1.03,1.01,0.99,0.98,1.07,0.99,1.03,1.03])
[inital_price * reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, returns[0:i+1]) for i in range(len(returns))]
```

Output:

```py
[70.7,
 72.114,
 74.27742,
 75.0201942,
 74.269992258,
 72.78459241284,
 77.8795138817388,
 77.10071874292142,
 79.41374030520907,
 81.79615251436535]
```